# Copy String from a PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am using VBA to loop through about 1,000 PDF's and extract a specific data element. I have the code that can find the specified string, but i need to copy the number that comes after the searched string. see image below of the text that is already highlighted from the search, but now i need to highlight the text that comes after.

I am using the sendkeys method to navigate the PDF documents, i have tried to use `Sendkey "+{Right}"` or `Sendkey "^+{Right}"` to highlight the data element, but the problem i am having is that once the search is complete, the pdf is stuck in like a scroll lock type of status, where `Sendkey "+{Right}"` just sends the document to the next page instead of highlighting the text to the right.

Would anyone know of a method to get the data element highlighted, and copied to my clipboard for pasting into the excel sheet?

Below is a snippet of my approach to getting the data from the pdf file.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

waitTime = Now
While DateDiff("s", waitTime, Now)
DoEvents
Wend

''send ctrl+f to open find function in pdf
SendKeys "^f", True
''insert our search string
SendKeys searchstring, True
''press enter to search
SendKeys "{Enter}", True
''escape to exit the search function
SendKeys "{ESC}", True
''attempt to highlight data element to right of search string
SendKeys "^+{Right}", True
''copy highlighted text
SendKeys "^c", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
''close pdf
SendKeys "^{F4}", True
thiswb.Activate
lrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lrow).Select
Selection.Value = MyFile
''paste data from clipboard
ClipboardToCell Range("B" & lrow)
```

thanks!

Comment: _SendKeys_ - Yuk!  Can you not use a [PDF API](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+api&oq=pdf+api&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is my first time working with PDFs in VBA; i dont know a whole lot about PDF API's, but i  will check it out. - Thanks!

Comment: Great, SendKeys is the _last_ resort, any other option if better.